# Mistake with loading double precision, floating point values on the registers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn some operations using intrinsic, but when I do the simple loading of double precision values on the registers like the following, it gives memory access violation error. I'm sure I'm doing some naive error. Could you please identify what my error is?

```
double a[2] = {10,12};
double * poinTer = &a[0];
__m128d v = _mm_load_pd(poinTer);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The array is not aligned properly.  Depends on the compiler you use, for MSVC it is __declspec(align(16)) double a[2] = {10,12};  For GCC it is `__attribute__ ((aligned (16)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` must be 16-bit aligned; depending from the compiler, you have to mark it as `__declspec(align(16))` (VC++) or `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` (gcc).

Answer (score 3):

The address you pass to `_mm_load_pd` must be 16 byte aligned. You'll need to take steps to ensure that is so.